# Script for automatically adding a new version number to current git branch

Tags: git, bash

I created this script for automatically bumping the version number of an external bundle in Symfony2 (just a standard git repo which needs tagging so composer pulls these new versions).

I just wanted to check if there were any issues with it (and share it if it is good and helpful for others) because I remember talking with a senior developer who would keep track of version numbers by outputting into a .version file, and I'm concerned that there might have been a very good reason he did that!

```
#!/bin/bash

#get highest tag number
VERSION=`git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`

#replace . with space so can split into an array
VERSION_BITS=(${VERSION//./ })

#get number parts and increase last one by 1
VNUM1=${VERSION_BITS[0]}
VNUM2=${VERSION_BITS[1]}
VNUM3=${VERSION_BITS[2]}
VNUM3=$((VNUM3+1))

#create new tag
NEW_TAG="$VNUM1.$VNUM2.$VNUM3"

echo "Updating $VERSION to $NEW_TAG"

#get current hash and see if it already has a tag
GIT_COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
NEEDS_TAG=`git describe --contains $GIT_COMMIT`

#only tag if no tag already (would be better if the git describe command above could have a silent option)
if [ -z "$NEEDS_TAG" ]; then
    echo "Tagged with $NEW_TAG (Ignoring fatal:cannot describe - this means commit is untagged) "
    git tag $NEW_TAG
    git push --tags
else
    echo "Already a tag on this commit"
fi
```

Comment: `[ -z $NEEDS_TAG ]` will not work the way you expect. When `$NEEDS_TAG` is empty it becomes `[ -z ]` which is seen as `[ -n -z ]` and returns true. You need to quote it. `[ -z "$NEEDS_TAG" ]`. That being said you can also, it seems, use the return code from `describe` instead of checking the output.

Comment: This is probably also more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes it seems to work without the quotes, but if it is safer with them I will add them. And awesome, I didn't realise there was a code review site now!

Comment: Yes, this happens to work for you because your two test cases collapse to the same thing. If you needed to only do the work when `$NEEDS_TAG` was empty this would instead always fail.

Comment: great, have updated. thanks